# jpa avoid query

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

i have the next class

```
@Entity    
@Table(name = "table_order")    
@IdClass(OrderPK.class)    
public class Order {    
   /** Unique identifier of the currency code in which the transaction was negociated. */

@Column(name = "TRADECURRE", nullable = false, length = 5)    
  private String tradeCurrencyCode;

/** Currency Entity for Trade. */    
  @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    
  @JoinColumns({     
     @JoinColumn(name = "TRADECURRE", referencedColumnName = "codigo", updatable = false, insertable = false) })    
  private Currency currencyEntity;

.. here get and sets    
}
```

then execute the next query:

```
StringBuilder jpaQuery = new StringBuilder();

StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();

jpaQuery.append("SELECT o, o.currencyEntity");

List orders = query.getResultList();
```

in this point the log of jpa show 2 querys executed, one to order table and other to Currency table.

bellow i write the next code (in the same class and method of the previous code)

```
for (Object orderElement : orders) {

  int indexArray = 0;
  Object[] orderArray = (Object[]) orderElement;
  Order orderEntity = (Order) orderArray [indexArray++];
  orderEntity.setCurrencyEntity((Currency) orderArray [indexArray++]);

}
```

When the line

```
orderEntity.setCurrencyEntity((Currency) orderArray [indexArray++]);
```

is executed, the query over the table currency is executed once again at database. I need avoid this query to fix some performance problems, i have all the data in the orderArray.

i'm using eclipselink 1.1

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you haven't told JPA to pre-fetch the `currentEntity` in the initial select (although I think that's what you were *trying* to do with `SELECT o, o.currencyEntity`). As a result, JPA has to fetch the `currentEntity` each time round the loop, and it's a real performance killer.

The way to do this with JPA is with a *fetch join* ([documented here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_fetch_joins)).  You'd write your query like this:

```
SELECT o from Order o LEFT JOIN FETCH o.currencyEntity
```

This also makes it easier to navigate the result set than with `SELECT o, o.currencyEntity`, since you'll only have a single entity returned, with its `currencyEntity` property intact:

```
List<Order> orders = query.getResultList();
for (Order order : orders) {
    // fully-populated, without requiring another database query
    Currency ccy = order.getCurrentEntity(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks, work for me, The only problem is I have JPA 1.0 at don't support nested fetch join